# applescript to find wallpaper image not working under Mac OS Mojave anymore

Tags: image, applescript, multiple-monitors, wallpaper

I used to use two applescripts to find out the file name of the actual wallpaper image from desktop 1 and desktop 2 (dual monitor mode) under Mac OS High Sierra. One script for the main monitor and another one for the second monitor. Under Mac OS Mojave only the script for desktop 1 is still working. The script for desktop 2 is not working anymore. Tried to find the problem but couldn't find a solution. I am not a experienced applescript writer. Hope somebody can help.

Script1 for desktop 1 (main monitor):

```
tell application "System Events"
    set posix_path to (pictures folder of desktop 1)
    set picPath to (POSIX file posix_path) as string
end tell
set thepictures to (do shell script "sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db \"SELECT data.value FROM preferences INNER JOIN data on preferences.key=16 and preferences.picture_id=1 and preferences.data_id=data.ROWID\"")
set fullPath to picPath as string
set rotationImage to fullPath & thepictures
tell application "Finder"
    try
        set aliasItem to item rotationImage
        if class of aliasItem is alias file then
            reveal original item of aliasItem
        end if
    end try
end tell
```

Script2 for desktop 2 (second monitor):

```
tell application "System Events"
    set posix_path to (pictures folder of desktop 2)
    set picPath to (POSIX file posix_path) as string
end tell
set thepictures to (do shell script "sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db \"SELECT data.value FROM preferences INNER JOIN data on preferences.key=16 and preferences.picture_id=5 and preferences.data_id=data.ROWID\"")
set fullPath to picPath as string
set rotationImage to fullPath & thepictures
tell application "Finder"
    try
        set aliasItem to item rotationImage
        if class of aliasItem is alias file then
            reveal original item of aliasItem
        end if
    end try
end tell
```

The expected result of the script is that finder is opening a window showing the file of the actual wallpaper image. It works with script1 but not with script2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Somewhere between High Sierra and Mojave the `preferences.picture_id` number for desktop 2 for the active wallpaper image has changed.

With High Sierra the `id` was `preferences.picture_id=5` and under Mojave it is `preferences.picture_id=7`.

Maybe this helps somebody else.